# SQL Server get distinct counts of name by each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset like :

```
ID  NAME
1   Aaron
2   Theon 
3   Jon Snow
4   Jon Snow
4   Dany
5   Arya
5   Robert
5   Tyrion
```

I need to add a new column to this that shows the output based on the number of distinct names per ID. So expected output would be:

```
ID  NAME  Mapping
1   Aaron   1
2   Theon   1
3   Jon Snow 1
4   Jon Snow 2
4   Dany     2   
5   Arya     3
5   Robert   3
5   Tyrion   3
```

I am confused about how to achieve this since I have tried a case statement where count(distinct(name)) does not return the right values.

Comment: Your expected output seems to have lost an `ID=4` record for `Dany`.

Comment: So it does. It should reflect 2 for ID 4 in the mapping column

Comment: Then why don't you update your question?

Comment: Updated to reflect changes

Answer (score 4):

You may try using `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) Mapping
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

Comment: This shows incorrect counts per ID. For ex., if an ID has 5 names attached to it, the mapping column shows a value of 10. Other counts are way off as well.

Comment: My answer matches the sample data you actually showed us.  If my answer does not meet your requirements, then edit your question and include the real data.

Comment: I am unable to post real data here. But the query looks like 'SELECT 
  DISTINCT(mn.Id)
,(n.FirstName+' '+n.LastName) AS 'Name'
, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY mn.Id) mapping FROM 
              dbo.note  mn 
JOIN DW_cxfreeze.dbo.name   n  ON n.loginameid = mn.Userid ORDER BY mn.Id'

Comment: I think the problem here is that you modified my answer and introduced changes.  Without seeing your real data, there is not much more I can do here.

Comment: @user10 . . . This answers the question that you actually asked.  If you have a different question -- or if this is not what you really intended -- then ask a *new* question.  It is unfair to change the question after it has been answered.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If you scour the above comments, I believe you will see evidence that the OP took my query and then modified it, the data in the question asked not actually being the real data/problem.  So, this is the source of the confusion IMHO.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think I know what the problem is. My question only points to the output of the data and not to how the data is structured. I can either update this question or ask another if you prefer. Which would you like?

Comment: Um...I prefer thay you ask a new question and that you not invalidate the 4 answers, and all work already done, given here.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to get `COUNT` of `DISTINCT` `Name` for each `ID`

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT Count(DISTINCT NAME) 
        FROM   @table T 
        WHERE  T1.id = T.id) Mapping 
FROM   @table T1
```

[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/GLMFV19729)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use below query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NAME)
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
GROUP  BY ID
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Other method (specif SQL Server, otherwise use INNER JOIN LATERAL):

```
SELECT *
FROM @table f1
CROSS APPLY
(
    select Count(*) Nb from @table f2
    where f2.ID=f1.ID
) f3
```